# Selenium Webdriver Java Error on Mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium, testng

I am getting the below error. This happened suddenly. I did not make any chnages to the framework. I Was just adding my Test Cases using [testng](/questions/tagged/testng). Any help could be of great help.

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
>   Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
>   System info: host: 'BANL12128KF1G3.local', ip: '172.18.152.47', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Can you indicate the test cases you added in your question?

Comment: I added the normal UI Test Cases which contain assertions. I remember there was a Java Update to 8. Could that be the reason?

Comment: what code you have written?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Error, your existing framework was developed using JAVA 1.6, when an java update was done it is not accepting it, downgrade your java version close the browser and try it should work else uninstall the browser and use the same version of browser which was earlier being used !!